# Laravel 5.7 | PHP 7.1.3 | Upload project to external server

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to upload project to external server.

I always did the same, that is:
1. I placed files on the server using FTP. I placed files from the public folder loosely, and put the rest of the files into a new folder.
3. I changed paths in index.php to 'project/vendor/autoload.php' etc.
4. I have changed the php versions for the domain.
5. Configured the .env file.

I've never had problems with it. Now I'm trying to put the project on the server and throwing me an error:

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/users/domain/public_html/project/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/multiphp/php7.1/usr/share/php:/home/lib/php7.1:/home/lib/php7.1/pear') in /home/users/domain/public_html/project/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
```

I checked php version. On server is actualy 7.1.12, in composer.json I have 7.1.3. This should probably not be a problem. Can anyone suggest me how to correct this error?

Answer (score 0):

If  composer versions differ, you may have to run `composer update` so that the right packages are paired. I also suggest to run `composer dump-autoload` to make sure the inclusion paths are rightly adjusted.

Comment: Should I use composer dump-autoload before placing files on the server or already on the server itself?

Comment: After you've placed the files on the server. Dump-autoload makes auto inclusion based on current setup structure

Comment: But how can I use composer in external server?